# non-daemonic Threads keep running in the call stack - Concept

Tags: python, multithreading

Using this code the threads keep running in the call stack instead of finishing. I don't understand why since I check the status of the queue in debug mode and it is empty. I also included my_queue.join() and verified that main continues its execution when the threads are done with the queue.

```
import queue
from urllib.request import urlopen, Request
import os
import threading


HEADER = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}

# Note: only URL:s ending on .jpg works
IMG_URLS = [
            "https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2017/03/08/13/06/dog-2126708__340.jpg",
            "https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/06/05/22/45/otter-1438381__340.jpg",
            "https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2014/10/22/14/43/otter-498046__340.jpg",
            "https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2017/10/23/23/43/otter-2883047__340.jpg"
            ]

# Change to desired folder
SAVE_FOLDER = r"C:\Users\xxxxxxxx"  
my_queue = queue.Queue()

def generate_queue(list):
    for url in list:
        my_queue.put(url)


def create_and_run_threads():
    number_threads=2
    for _ in range(number_threads):
        threading.Thread(target=worker, args=(my_queue,)).start()

def worker(q):
    while q:
        url=q.get()
        download_img(url)
        my_queue.task_done()


def download_img(url):
    img_bytes = request_and_open(url)
    img_name = url.split("/")[-1]
    file_path = os.path.join(SAVE_FOLDER, img_name)

    with open(file_path, "wb") as img:
        img.write(img_bytes)
        print(f"Downloading image: {img_name}")

def request_and_open(URL):
    request = Request(URL, headers=HEADER)
    url_info_byte = urlopen(request, timeout=20).read()
    return url_info_byte


def main():
    generate_queue(IMG_URLS)
    create_and_run_threads()
    my_queue.join()
    print("All done!")

    

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

This is how the call stack looks like when all the program is executed [Call stack threads running](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TwCqb.png). While I expect them to be done.

[Process does not finishes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i3msw.png)

What am I missing? What is preventing them to close themselves?

EDIT: I tried using a daemon thread and now they close.
Then I don't understand why non-daemonic thread keep running even when all tasks are done.

```
threading.Thread(target=worker, args=(my_queue,), daemon=True).start()
```

Comment: Please note that I am aware this code does not reflect the most efficient way of doing that task. I am just learning threads so please don't put much effort on improving the code, just focus on the problem.

Comment: you have a race condition on the queue, also you should be using a threadpool, don't reinvent the wheel.

Comment: Did you mean to check `q.empty()` instead of just `q`? (Though even with that fix, I think you still have the race condition Ahmed mentions)

Comment: Apparently there's no race condition or deadlock. I changed to daemonic threads and now they close. But I have a concept gap so I don't understand why.

Comment: the interpreter doesn't exit until all non-daemonic threads are terminated, but it can kill daemonic ones when exiting, this doesn't fix your original two problems of not doing `while not q.empty():` and having a race condition, these bugs are just no-longer preventing your application from closing, exploration through experimentation is usually a bad things to do, instead consider reading python's implementation of Threadpool and learn from it.

Comment: I don't know why they call a list of threads a 'call stack'. Threads aren't in the call stack, by definition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your worker function is:

```py
def worker(q):
    while q:
        url=q.get()
        download_img(url)
        my_queue.task_done()
```

The test `while q:` will cause you to loop forever since `q` is not `None` (i.e. you are not testing whether the queue is empty or not, but just whether it exists). You then are calling `q.get()`, which is a blocking `get` that will wait for something to be on the queue if the queue is currently empty. So this loop will never terminate and that is why your thread will never terminate unless it is a daemon thread.  There are two ways of fixing this:

Since you have already put all the URL's on the queue prior to starting the threads you can do either use a non-blocking `get` and catch a `queue.empty` exception:

```py
def worker(q):
    while True:
        try:
            url = q.get_nowait()
        except queue.Empty:
            return
        else:
            download_img(url)
            my_queue.task_done()
```

Alternatively, since we are not dealing with a `multiprocessing.Queue` instance where the `empty` method is not reliable, we can use it here:

```py
def worker(q):
    while not q.empty():
        url = q.get_nowait()
        download_img(url)
        my_queue.task_done()
```

I would prefer this second version.

Note that if you started the threads before putting the URLs on the queue, neither code would work because of the race condition (the queue might be temporarily empty between successive `put` calls). The way to handle this would be to add `N` *sentinel* items on the queue following the URLs, where `N` is the number of threads that will be getting values from the queue and a sentinel item is any value that could not be mistaken for an actual URL, e.g. `None`. Then each thread does blocking get calls until it retrieves a sentinel value when it would then return (i.e. terminate). Note that in the following code that demonstrates this technique, I have removed from global scope definitions because some functions were accessing these values as globals and other functions were being passed these global as arguments, which is inconsistent.

```py
import queue
from urllib.request import urlopen, Request
import os
import threading

HEADER = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}
N_THREADS = 2
# Change to desired folder
SAVE_FOLDER = r"C:\Users\xxxxxxxx"

def generate_queue(q, urls):
    for url in urls: # Note that the name list should not be used
        q.put(url)
    for _ in range(N_THREADS):
        q.put(None)


def create_and_run_threads(q):
    for _ in range(N_THREADS):
        threading.Thread(target=worker, args=(q,)).start()

def worker(q):
    while True:
        url = q.get()
        if url is None: # sentinel
            q.task_done() # we still need this!
            return
        download_img(url)
        q.task_done()


def download_img(url):
    img_bytes = request_and_open(url)
    img_name = url.split("/")[-1]

    file_path = os.path.join(SAVE_FOLDER, img_name)

    with open(file_path, "wb") as img:
        img.write(img_bytes)
        print(f"Downloading image: {img_name}")

def request_and_open(URL):
    request = Request(URL, headers=HEADER)
    url_info_byte = urlopen(request, timeout=20).read()
    return url_info_byte


def main():
    # Note: only URL:s ending on .jpg works
    img_urls = [
                "https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2017/03/08/13/06/dog-2126708__340.jpg",
                "https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/06/05/22/45/otter-1438381__340.jpg",
                "https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2014/10/22/14/43/otter-498046__340.jpg",
                "https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2017/10/23/23/43/otter-2883047__340.jpg"
                ]

    my_queue = queue.Queue()
    # Note we have reversed the order of the next two statements
    create_and_run_threads(my_queue)
    generate_queue(my_queue, img_urls)
    my_queue.join()
    print("All done!")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks a lot for your answer. It works now!!
But I don't understand why "while q: " does not check whether it is empty or not, just like lists (iterate until they are empty) - how are queues different in this sense?

Thanks for the tip of not using "list" as name of variable...

Comment: See [this explanation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing). A `queue` does not define a `__len__` method unlike a `list`. If an object defines such a method then when it returns 0 the reference to that object is considered `False`. A `queue` instance does not have a `__len__` method. Do not thank me but rather *Accept* the answer. See [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Comment: Nice thanks a lot.
I need at least 15 reputation to cast a vote, but I have Accepted the answer and my feedback has been recorded.

Comment: I am not asking you to upvote the answer but rather to Accept it. Under each answer, there is a checkmark icon on the left side. Click the checkmark next to the answer that you want to accept. It appears you have not done this yet.

Comment: Aha I am so sorry. Not need to say I am new here, still many things to learn. Sorry didn't read the full link.... my apologies https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers